# How to use custom JSON (not GeoJSON) with Highcharts map?

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary, highcharts, geojson

I have JSON files containing a list of polygons coordinates with some properties (global, and also for each 'polygon'). I want to draw these polygons and display their properties with a tooltip using Highcharts map. Usually Highcharts needs standard GeoJSON, but here I must keep the JSON files I have because they are used by other programs. Do you have any idea how to deal with the filling of 'series' and 'mapData' from custom JSON ?

That is clear for simple charts how to do a small function to create tables, but for maps I'm a bit lost ...

**EDIT:** my (simplified) example of JSON:

```
{
"Version" : "1.0.0",
"Number of Elements" : 3043,

"Elements": [{
    "Index" : 0,
    "coordinates": [ [1768, 98], [1784, 90], [1789, 81], [1791, 68], [1785, 52], [1774, 41], [1767, 39], [1742, 48], [1736, 53], [1734, 59], [1736, 69], [1748, 90] ],
    "Surface" : 995.55,
    "Perimeter" : 114.74,
    "Center X" : 1137.53,
    "Center Y" : 43.79
},{
    "Index" : 1,
    "coordinates": [ [1709, 119], [1725, 112], [1739, 102], [1744, 91], [1733, 66], [1708, 49], [1698, 51], [1685, 60], [1677, 68], [1674, 81], [1675, 90], [1682, 105], [1697, 116] ],
    "Surface" : 1414.90,
    "Perimeter" : 136.44,
    "Center X" : 1101.35,
    "Center Y" : 54.69
},{
    "Index" : 2,
    "coordinates": [ [1648, 109], [1664, 97], [1667, 90], [1666, 80], [1657, 68], [1617, 52], [1611, 53], [1603, 64], [1613, 79], [1616, 95], [1626, 106] ],
    "Surface" : 973.50,
    "Perimeter" : 120.49,
    "Center X" : 1055.04,
    "Center Y" : 52.38
} ...
```

I would like to draw these polygons, and use a tooltip to display the "Surface" and "Perimeter" properties.

Comment: I think you need to use GeoJSON in this case. You can read Highcharts docs for information how to make custom GeoJSON maps: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/custom-geojson-maps

Comment: So you don't think there is another way to use an Highcharts map than load a GeoJSON ? Of course one can 'translate' our JSON to a standard GeoJSON, but I want to know if there is a simpler way.

Comment: Could you show us your custom json and give us more specifications about map you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in fact the answer was really simple.

First of all reading the specs here :

http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html

I finally decided to convert the JSON inside the Highchart function using this module :

https://github.com/caseypt/geojson.js

which convert very easily JSON to GeoJSON.

Problem solved !